# TypeError: namefunction is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

Following my code:

HTML:

```
<input id="test" onkeydown="test();" type="text"/>
```

JS:

```
function pl(id){
    return id;
}

function test(){
 id = "test";
 alert(pl(id));   
}
```

Why the browser return `TypeError: test is not a function`?

Comment: Maybe your JavaScript is above the HTML?

Comment: That code won't cause that problem. You appear to have reduced your reduced test case too much.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum — They are just function definitions, that can't be the problem.

Comment: @jsve the same... http://jsfiddle.net/9tFHA/1/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum no, test it with jsfiddle.

Comment: because the fiddle is set to run onload! Change it so the JavaScript is in the head. TADA

Comment: @user3076752 the jsfiddle is set to run onload like epascarello said. On the right, change it from onload to 'head'. Also, avoid inline onkeydown handlers and look up addEventListener .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a problem with the code in the question, but the [live example of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/9tFHA/1/) you provided, has your function definitions wrapped in another function (which is executed `onload`).

They are scoped to their containing function, so you cannot access them with an `onclick` attribute (which can only touch global variables).

[Bind your event handlers programatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead.

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener(
    "keydown",
    test
    );
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/9tFHA/2/